# In reactive programming how to elegantly close the connection in the database connection pool

Tags: java, spring, mysql-connector, reactive, webflux

Recently I am learning Spring WebFlux. And When I try to close my connection in the connection pool, it does not work!

Code is like this:

```java
return connectionPool.create().flatMap(connection -> {
    Mono<Result> result = Mono.from(connection.createStatement("").execute());
    connection.close();
    return result;
    })
    .flatMap(body -> Mono.from(body.map(((row, rowMetadata) -> row.get(0, String.class)))));
```

I have noticed that the `close` function would return a `Publish< Void>` object, but I do not know how to deal with the two dataflows (`Mono< Result>` and `Publish< Void>`) together!

Could someone help me?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Just so you know, best practice is to include the text of your code in the body of your question, rather than as an image. You can update your post using the 'Edit' button. (Check out the discussion behind this advice in this post on meta: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a `doFinally()` handler to the `Mono` so that it can make sure that connection is closed whether the stream processing completes normally or not.

Something like this:

```
.flatMap(c -> 
    Mono.from(c.createStatement("query goes here...")
      .execute())
      .doFinally((st) -> close(c))
 )
```